# Shiny for choropleth map with two selection lists

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny, r-sf, choropleth

I have `df`, and I wanted to create a shiny application that gets updated based on the value of two selection lists, one for picking an `indicator`, and the other for choosing the `subgroup`. I also create a function for produce the choropleth based on the values if its input. The function works fine when it is not run inside the shiny but return error within shiny (object of type ‘closure’).

```
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(rnaturalearth)

# Creating a test data frame
df <- tribble(
  ~Country, ~ISO3, ~Subgroup, ~Indicator, ~Value,
  "Jordan", "JOR", "Group1", "Ind1", 25.6,
  "Turkey", "TUR", "Group1", "Ind1", 56.4,
  "Jordan", "JOR", "Group1", "Ind2", 63.4,
  "Turkey", "TUR", "Group1", "Ind2", 87.5,
  "Jordan", "JOR", "Group2", "Ind1", 13.2,
  "Turkey", "TUR", "Group2", "Ind1", 22.6,
  "Jordan", "JOR", "Group2", "Ind2", 44.9,
  "Turkey", "TUR", "Group2", "Ind2", 78.5,
  
)

# Function to use for mapping an indicator
MapValue <- function(data, var, group){
  
  df <-  df %>%
    filter(Indicator == var & Subgroup == group)
  
  df_join <- rnaturalearth::ne_countries(returnclass = "sf") %>% 
    left_join(df, by = join_by(iso_a3 == ISO3))
  
  plot(df_join["Value"],
       border = 'grey80',
       pal = colorRampPalette(c("white", "darkgreen"))(100),
       breaks = c(0:100))
}

# Shiny 
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Shiny for Indicators"), 
  
  sidebarLayout(

      selectInput(inputId = "var", 
                  label = "Choose a variable to display", 
                  choices = list("Ind1", "Ind2"), 
                  selected = "Ind1"),
      
      selectInput(inputId = "groups", 
                  label = "Choose a Subgroup to display", 
                  choices = list("Group1", "Group2"), 
                  selected = "Group1")
    ),
    
    mainPanel(plotOutput("map"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
  output$map <- renderPlot({
    
    args$data <- df
    args$var <- switch(input$var,
                       "Ind1"= df[df$Indicator == "Ind1", ],
                       "Ind2" = df[df$Indicator == "Ind2",]
    )
    args$group <- switch(input$groups,
                         "Group1"= df[df$Subgroup == "Group1", ],
                         "Group2" = df[df$Subgroup == "Group2", ]
    )
    do.call(MapValue, args)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a couple of things going on here:

1. You should put the data in the server function, rather than just defining it outside.
2. The `MapValue()` function had `data` as an argument, but you were calling it in the function as `df`

```r
MapValue <- function(data, var, group){
  
  df <-  df %>%
    filter(Indicator == var & Subgroup == group)
  
...
}
```

you can fix this this either by using `MapValue <- function(df, var, group)` or by using `data` instead of `df` in the body of the function.

3. The `MapValue()` function `group` and `var` arguments should just be character strings identifying the desired group and indicator, not the values of the group and indicators themselves.  So, all you need to do is use `group = input$groups` and `var = input$var` and it should work.
4. You're using `args` as a list, but you don't initialize the list first. So, before you start filling up `args` you need to do `args <- list()`.

One other point, the `object of type 'closure' is not subsettable` error generally happens when you think something is defined as data, but R thinks it is a function.  Both `df` and `args` are functions in R.  When making objects, the best practice would be to stay away from function names - that will make the debugging a bit easier.  My default is always `dat`. See below for a full working App.

---

### Full App

```r
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(shiny)

# Creating a test data frame

# Function to use for mapping an indicator
MapValue <- function(data, var, group){
  
  data <-  data %>%
    filter(Indicator == var & Subgroup == group)
  
  df_join <- rnaturalearth::ne_countries(returnclass = "sf") %>% 
    left_join(data, by = join_by(iso_a3 == ISO3))
  
  plot(df_join["Value"],
       border = 'grey80',
       pal = colorRampPalette(c("white", "darkgreen"))(100),
       breaks = c(0:100))
}

# Shiny 
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Shiny for Indicators"), 
  
  sidebarLayout(
    
    selectInput(inputId = "var", 
                label = "Choose a variable to display", 
                choices = list("Ind1", "Ind2"), 
                selected = "Ind1"),
    
    selectInput(inputId = "groups", 
                label = "Choose a Subgroup to display", 
                choices = list("Group1", "Group2"), 
                selected = "Group1")
  ),
  
  mainPanel(plotOutput("map"))
)


server <- function(input, output){
  dat <- tribble(
    ~Country, ~ISO3, ~Subgroup, ~Indicator, ~Value,
    "Jordan", "JOR", "Group1", "Ind1", 25.6,
    "Turkey", "TUR", "Group1", "Ind1", 56.4,
    "Jordan", "JOR", "Group1", "Ind2", 63.4,
    "Turkey", "TUR", "Group1", "Ind2", 87.5,
    "Jordan", "JOR", "Group2", "Ind1", 13.2,
    "Turkey", "TUR", "Group2", "Ind1", 22.6,
    "Jordan", "JOR", "Group2", "Ind2", 44.9,
    "Turkey", "TUR", "Group2", "Ind2", 78.5,
    
  )
  
  output$map <- renderPlot({
    args <- list()
    args$data <- dat 
    args$var <- input$var
    args$group <- input$groups
    do.call(MapValue, args)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```